# How to set Maximum provisioned capacity for DynamoDB using cloud formation yaml config?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am using yaml config file to create dynamo DB table and set some configurations:

```
ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

This sets the desired minimum number of consistent reads/writes. If it is possible, how can I set the Maximum provisioned capacity for read/write?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the example you have used you are not setting the minimum provisioned capacity within auto scaling, you are setting the provision capacity.

To configure an auto-scaling resource you should use [AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationautoscaling-scalabletarget.html)

Which has this structure:

```
Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
Properties:
  MaxCapacity: Integer
  MinCapacity: Integer
  ResourceId: String
  RoleARN: String
  ScalableDimension: String
  ScheduledActions: 
    - ScheduledAction
  ServiceNamespace: String
```

And here is a DynamoDB example:

```
Resources:
  DDBTable:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "ArtistId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "Concert"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "TicketSales"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "ArtistId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "Concert"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        -
          IndexName: "GSI"
          KeySchema:
            -
              AttributeName: "TicketSales"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: "KEYS_ONLY"
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
  WriteCapacityScalableTarget:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 15
      MinCapacity: 5
      ResourceId: !Join
        - /
        - - table
          - !Ref DDBTable
      RoleARN: !GetAtt ScalingRole.Arn
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
  ScalingRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: "root"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
                  - "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
                  - "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm"
                  - "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"
                  - "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
                  - "cloudwatch:SetAlarmState"
                  - "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms"
                Resource: "*"
  WriteScalingPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WriteAutoScalingPolicy
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref WriteCapacityScalableTarget
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        TargetValue: 50.0
        ScaleInCooldown: 60
        ScaleOutCooldown: 60
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization
```

Comment: I got the error:

`yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!Join'`

                      `ResourceId:

                        Fn::Join:

                        - /

                        - - table

                          - {Ref: table}`

worked for me though.